# Easy ways to quit and restart an entire script?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a Discord bot that I'm writing a restart function for. I want to be able to run one command that will not only stop the script, but kill and restart it, so I can implement updates quickly. I've realized that the Discord API is not sufficient for this so I haven't added it to the tags. The simplest way I can think of is by using two scripts that call each other.

Every resource I've found references either a module (?) called PM2 or a programming language called VBScript. I do not want to mess around with a module that automatically reboots every single time I save, and I especially don't want to try learning a new language.

Here is my pseudocode showing what I'm aiming for:

```
[bot.js]
function reboot() {
    runFile(`./reboot.js`)
}

[reboot.js]
kill (`./bot.js`)
runFile(`./bot.js`)
```

The result I'm hoping for is for bot.js to run reboot.js. Reboot.js will then quit bot.js and run it again. Then reboot.js will close. I don't care about any processes already running on bot.js.

Of course, if there are even simpler ways to do this, please let me know. I need as much simplicity as I can get.

Comment: What about a master-slave like structure? You have `bot` as slave, then in `master` you run it as child process. When update you just kill then restart the child process

Comment: @hackape Assuming I understand you correctly, that would restart the process but not the script. It's important to restart the entire script because otherwise it continues running using the previous code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Discord bots, but if you want to start, kill and restart processes programmatically in NodeJS then you want to look into the `child_process` module.

https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process

Answer (score 1):

[PM2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/) is a process manager and would do the trick for you.

It's easily installed: `npm install pm2 -g`

Start your bot: `pm2 start bot.js --name "Discord Bot"`

Code-wise, you'll want to simply [kill the process](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_exit_code). PM2, being a process manager, will restart it for you.

Answer (score 1):

I've figured it out. I used the child-process module built into node.js.

```
[bot.js]

var cp = require('child_process');
function reboot() {
    var ls = cp.spawn('node', ['reboot.js']);
    client.destroy()
}


[full contents of reboot.js]

var cp = require('child_process');
var ls = cp.spawn('node', ['bot.js']);
```

(posting all this for fellow noobs to use)

Edit: Note that after restarting, console outputs no longer work, as it's running from reboot.js rather than directly from the terminal.